# How to apply sound distortion in actionscript-3?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, effects

Let's say the sound input is either an embedded mp3 file or the microphone.

Is there an example of how to make it sound **demonic and creepy**, or like a **radio transmission from the battlefield** in actionscript-3 dynamically on runtime.

Reference:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAY88WH0FcU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you simply can't with the microphone, unless you first send it to a server.

With an audio file (embedded or not), you can distort it by playing with its bytes ([ref](http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/)), but its not at all a trivial task (I'm not aware of any library for "easy" sound processing).

Comment: Are there any articles about doing such sound processing? I'd read them and implement such a library but i am not really familiar with sound processing per se.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... I've seen a few examples of pitch and reverse, but the kind of distortion you are looking for seems far more complex... I wouldn't know where to begin either, sorry :S

Comment: It's not an easy task at all, but you might want to try reading Andre Michelle's blog (he's one of the guys behind hobnox), he has a number of posts on distorting audio: http://blog.andre-michelle.com/.